# Redshift UNLOAD ignores DATESTYLE

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Issue is quite simple. In a single session, I run:

```
set DATESTYLE to 'SQL,DMY';
```

Then I run an `UNLOAD` command, using a basic `SELECT * FROM [table name]`.  The table has a `DATE` column.

The file output to S3 does not use the format I specified. How can I change the date format output by `UNLOAD`?

Answer (score 1):

We created an AWS support ticket, and this was the response:

> Upon reading your case I gather that you are looking to see if in UNLOAD command you could add a Data Conversion Parameter to specify the date/timestamp format instead of using the date conversions in select statement. Please let me know if I am missing out on any information.
>
> Unfortunately at the moment we do not currently have the functionality to add the date parameter and the only way to change that would be to do it in the SQL query. I have created a feature request for the particular use case that you have requested but I wouldn't be able to give you an ETA for when the feature would be released.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Datetime Format Strings - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html) to output the date in a specific style, eg:

```
select sysdate,
to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS') as seconds,
to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS.MS') as milliseconds,
to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS:US') as microseconds;

timestamp           | seconds  | milliseconds | microseconds   
--------------------+----------+--------------+----------------
2015-04-10 18:45:09 | 18:45:09 | 18:45:09.325 | 18:45:09:325143
```

Comment: yes, i realize i can convert the output using the select statement.. but for various reasons, that is not an option. Hence the question is more around having UNLOAD pay attention to a date format setting. is there anything i can do other than the set datestyle method, which might actually be reflected in the output?